# Scraping data tables with python requests

Tags: web-scraping, datatables, python-requests

I have been scraping a few sites that contain tables, most of them work with the following code if the table itself ah a class name. (the idea is to scrape the data and put it in a csv file)

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib

url = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors")
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = bsObj.find_all("table", {"class": "wikitable"})[0]
rows = table.find_all("tr")
csv_file = open("proxies2.csv", 'a', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
try:
    for rows in rows:
        csvRow = []
        for cell in rows.find_all(["td", "th"]):
            csvRow.append(cell.get_text())
        writer.writerow(csvRow)
finally:
    csv_file.close()
```

When I used the website ([link](https://proxydb.net/)); the first column returns more information than I want, this is probably due to the fact that the first column has a hyperlink. Any help on this would be truly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by more information? What kind of requirement you have? Be more clear to help you appropriately.

Comment: Might just get away with removing newlines... eg: `cell.get_text().replace('\n', '')` ?

Comment: Use this line to kick out script tags from that page in order for getting rid of unwanted items `[script.extract() for script in soup.find_all("script")]`

Comment: the info I retrieve from the wikipedia site would be the visible text in the field (eg: Rob Pike), whereas the site i am trying to use, gives me the following info: [link](https://ibb.co/hYWGHp). I don't think that removing blank lines would help as the extra info is not blank lines but code surrounding the text I would like to achieve. (view picture attached to see what i am saying)

Comment: @SIM , I am not sure how I would implement that in my code, could you maybe post a version with it integrated?

Comment: Use this `[script.extract() for script in bsObj.find_all("script")]` line just after `bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")`. Make sure you replace the class name `wikitable` with `table` and the rest are as it is. Btw, my suggestion is applicable for [this link](https://proxydb.net/). Thanks.

Comment: @SIM You suggested method seems to work but leves the whole "Proxies" column blank, I am looking for it to leave out the extra tags but keep the visible info for that column, eg: "01.50.1.2:80". Following your suggestion I got [the following](https://gyazo.com/d4e68606eb4df5eba03878f0ff570d33) . Thanks

Comment: Thats because the proxy content is encrypted within javascript. If you wanna get what you want to then you can do the same using selenium. I hope that should solve the issue.

Comment: @SIM gotcha, thanks for the help :)